# cannot store php string variables into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$address = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";    
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$plugin='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip;
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents($plugin)); 
$country = $geo['geoplugin_countryName'];
$city = $geo['geoplugin_city'];

var_dump($country) // string(6)"Serbia"
var_dump($city) // string(8)"Belgrade"

try
{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO visits (country,city,address) VALUES (:country,:city,:address)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':country'=>$country,
                  ':city'=>$city,
                  ':address'=>$address
                  ));
} catch ( PDOException $exception )
{
    echo "PDO error :" . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

`address` is stored into the table, but `country` and `city` ARE NOT. Both columns are of `varchar` type.

`NULL` value is displayed instead.

There is no error reported.

Just for test, I changed `':country'=>$country`, to `':country'=>"USA"`, and it works.

Comment: Why are you using "var_dump".  Here does not make sense

Comment: i think it's a problem of quotes...

Comment: @maysaghira, where do you see that problem in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the parameters -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visits (country,city,address) VALUES (:country,:city,:address)";
$sql->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: You can pass an associative array into the `execute` function with PDO prepared statements, check Docs (example #2) http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php.

Comment: This indicates to me that $country and $city are not being set as you would expect them to be.